# Unable to upload file to server with wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload, upload

[image]I am trying to upload files from react app to server via wcf service. The code is working fine on local server. The service is hosted on godaddy servers. When I try to upload file the server gives error 400 bad request. The code is working fine on local server and creating folder and saving the file in the right folder. What other details I should provide.

```
public void UploadFile(Stream stream)
    {

        MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(stream);
        string uploadpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/");

        if (parser.Success)
        {
            string filename = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parser.Filename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(uploadpath + filename, parser.FileContents);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error");
        } 
        }
      }

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceBehaviors">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="web" >
        <webHttp></webHttp>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="largeMessage" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00">
        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="mailService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehaviors">
      <endpoint address="" contract="mailService.IService1" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessage" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"  />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
      To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
      Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<security>

</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The file size is not big 127kb only

[image]

Postman is showing that access denied to the path.

Comment: it seems that stream should be the only parameter to call uploadfile method. How to include the parameters also please help.

Comment: I have updated the code without the parameters. Still giving 400 bad request error.

Comment: What is the detailed error and is it caused by cross-domain?

Comment: 400 bad request. Rest of the service is working so it is not a cross origin error.

Comment: There are too many reasons for the 400 error. Is there a detailed error message?

Comment: No just a short message saying 400 bad request

Comment: If you can, can you provide a screenshot of the error? Because based on your existing information, I really don’t know what caused the 400 error.

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: Is it possible to use Postman?You need to debug the server-side to see what happened inside the service.

Comment: @DingPeng add the screenshot of postman. Showing access denied to the path. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the permission on the server for images folder and I worked.